# iOS Barcode Efficient Scanner

Tags: ios, barcode, barcode-scanner

I am working on an iOS application and I am interested to embed some already developed and tested barcode scanner into it. I tried zxing but this never extract the numbers out of it. My goal is to scan this image and get 24 characters out of it.

If there is not a already developed thing, I would like to build one myself. How should I start in order to create it from scratch for 1D barcodes initially?

[image]

Using zxing I am using this piece of code now.

```
- (IBAction)scanPressed:(id)sender {

    ZXingWidgetController *widController = [[ZXingWidgetController alloc] initWithDelegate:self showCancel:YES OneDMode:YES];

    zxing::oned::Code128Reader *code128Reader = new zxing::oned::Code128Reader();
    MultiFormatOneDReader *mfReader = [[MultiFormatOneDReader alloc] initWithReader:code128Reader];
    NSSet *readers = [[NSSet alloc ] initWithObjects:mfReader,nil];
    [mfReader release];

    widController.readers = readers;
    [readers release];

    NSBundle *mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    widController.soundToPlay =
    [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[mainBundle pathForResource:@"beep-beep" ofType:@"aiff"] isDirectory:NO];
    [self presentModalViewController:widController animated:YES];
    [widController release];
}
```

Comment: What is the type of barcode you need to scan? Make sure the library you use is able to scan the specific type of barcode you will be using (this is not an EAN-13 barcode and does not seem to be any other EAN family, so ask yourself first what barcode type and standard is it to then choose an appropriate lib)

Comment: I still need to figure out the type. What do you think if I simply read the characters from this image assuming I just need these 24 numbers. Why may I read the lines and spaces to figure out the number?

Comment: Because number recognition is much harder than barcode reading. Barcode are specifically designed to be easier to read, even in bad lighting conditions, different zoom levels, perspective distortion, rotation and much more: they are easy to detect even with other images and text around, and easy to decode whatever the distortion, (they are scale and rotation independant).

Comment: OCR and numbers recognition is much more tricky and random (e.g. "6" and "8" characters will probably look the same for your recognition algorithm), it is more complicated to make them rotation/perspective/distortion/scale-independant and it will have a much higher error rate (especially in bad lightning conditions, or if there is some dust on the image, etc) than barcode reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried ZXing SDK first but it didn't work. I then tried ZBar SDK which worked just amazingly great.

If in future someone would need the same thing I am going to post the link which helped me make it work.

http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/sdkdoc/tutorial.html

Comment: I initially started of with zxing, which gave me problems with errors and stuff. Eventually got it to work, but not with 1d barcodes. I have now resorted to zBar and got it working in 10 minutes. Thanks for the link. Saved me a lot of time

Answer (score 2):

If this is a "Code 128" barcode, pay attention of the variant of the code.

For example if using zxing you successfully scanned the code but the decoded values do not match the numbers under the barcode, that's probably because zxing decoded the barcode bytes successfully but didn't render the result using the expected alphabet.

Code 128 exists in three variants:

- Code 128 A which uses the alphabet `"!#$%&'()*+.-/0123456789:;<=>?@ ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`
- Code 128 A which uses the wider alphabet ``` "!#$%&'()*+.-/0123456789:;<=>?@ ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`` abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~ ```
- Code 128 C which encodes numbers `0-9`

Maybe zxing returns the 128-A or 128-B interpretation of the barcode and not the 128-C variant? In such cases it would mean that the scanning works correctly but you may force the barcode format so it can interpret it right.

Comment: zxing just keeps looking at the image and never ends so it seems doesn't work

Comment: Did you try to give the Code128 int to the scanner? I never used zxing before but looking at its source code there are probably sthg to do with the ZXDecodeHints class/enum to make zxing know this is a Code_128 barcode and help it decode it? (Anyway I just saw in Code128Reader.cpp that once it knows to look for Code128 codes, it can detect automatically if it is a type A,B or C 128 code... but first make sure you told him about the barcode type to help the recognition)

Comment: I downloaded the whole source code from code.google.com and loaded it into xcode and then loaded it into my iphone 3GS and then tried to scan the barcode. It is taking long time and I give up.

Comment: You seems right here. I need to figure it out and hint it about Code_128

Comment: With this code it still doesn't work. I read somewhere which says zxing won't work on iPhone 3 or 3GS but on 4 and 4S. I don't have 3GS device so if you have any of the device on which you can test that would be good to help me see if it's the code which is wrong or that theory. It would definitely help in future to others. I try to someone here having iPhone 4.

Comment: cool didn't know this SDK (never had to integrate a barcode scanner yet in my apps anyway ^^) good to know :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm wrong about this the zxing code bases for iphone only allows for QR codes.
From the website site http://code.google.com/p/zxing/

> There are also additional modules which are contributed and/or
>   intermittently maintained:
>
> ```
> zxing.appspot.com: The source behind our web-based barcode generator
> csharp: Partial C# port
> cpp: Partial C++ port
> **iphone: iPhone client + port to Objective C / C++ (QR code only)**
> jruby: Ruby wrapper
> actionscript: partial port to Actionscript
> ```

Comment: From their FAQ they say it's supported on iPhone 4 and greater because new these devices have only supported API for live capturing.